# how to avoid going out of the page when using minipage and flalign environments

Tags: align, minipage, flalign

I am placing two equations side by side using both `minipage` and `flaign` environments. For a reason that I cannot figure out, the equations labels go out of the page. What might I be doing wrong here? I've tried both `textwidth` and `linewidth`, but it did not make any difference.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{flalign}
a = b \label{a} 
\end{flalign}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{flalign}
c = d= =e  + f \label{d} 
\end{flalign}
\end{minipage}
```

I receive `Overfull \hbox (14.99998pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 311--321`.

[image]

Comment: you should show an example but probably you want `\noindent` before the first minipage.

Comment: That did solve the problem. Thanks. If you post that as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Aside: The default value of `\parindent` is 15pt in the standard LaTeX document classes. If you get an `Overfull \hbox` warning message involving an amount of 15pt (or, as above, 14.99998pt), your first thought should be about something likely being shifted by `\parindent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines is indented, so you want `\noindent` at the start, or place in `\begin{center}...\end{center}` or similar